# Is it safe to power a monitor without grounding?

Tags: grounding

After viewing https://superuser.com/questions/461898/earthing-is-it-important-for-laptops and learning about [double insulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Appliance_classes#Class_II), it seems that an appliance is safe as long as there is no way that the chassis can become live if a wire becomes disconnected internally. My computer monitor has a plastic case, why then does it have a 3-prong grounded plug? Is there is a risk that the screen itself could conduct electricity or that the plastic is not insulating enough?

I ask because I am looking to make a [MagicMirror](https://magicmirror.builders/) style display with probably a wood frame and would like to use a less bulky cord to power it but naturally I don't want to kill anyone.

Comment: Can you provide details of your monitor and the plug connector.  Many monitors are double insulated and don't need an earth connection for safety but may use a three pin plug because for example in the UK the earth pin is longer and you can't access 'line' and 'neutral' unless this pin is there.  I have some devices with a plastic 'earth' just for this purpose.  Alternatively you may want a safety earth if you have accessable metal parts on signal connectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the monitor has a ground connection on the mains plug, it has a power supply which requires grounding, and must be connected to ground. Otherwise ground currents of the mains input EMI filter would flow in the video cable if you have connected it to a grounded PC. If it is disconnected, all the parts like connectors have half mains AC voltage on it. If connecting to other equipment, it may damage something if ground connections are not good and only signal wires connect. Do not run ground-requiring devices without ground, it is there for a purpose.

Comment: Wasn't thinking about the ports etc., thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If grounding (PE) contact is in there, then it must be preserved, unless you really know what you are doing. Having things grounded properly, *if they are designed to be*, is very important if you would try connecting or disconnecting two devices. Both grounded properly through the receptacle -> no potential between cables' grounds or shields when they are in disconnected state. Leaving PE disconnected may (will) create virtual ground (depending on the internal circuit of the device) which may be up to half of mains AC voltage potentially shocking the person connecting or disconnecting the devices, and potentially damaging inputs/outputs of the devices.

Comment: Great answer! I wish I could mark both as correct.